# How do I get a variable from JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I tried a lot scripts and none of them worked.

**This is the code I have:**

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://video.foxnews.com/v/feed/video/1228085488001.js"); 
var_dump(json_decode($contents, true));
```

**It outputs:**

> array(2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["version"]=> string(3) "2.0"
>   } ["channel"]=> array(2) { ["title"]=> array(0) { } ["item"]=>
>   array(2) { ["title"]=> string(49) "Should Government Stay Out of
>   Foreclosure Crisis?" ["media-content"]=> array(32) { ["@attributes"]=>
>   array(1) { ["url"]=> string(60)
>   "http://media2.foxnews.com/102011/ff_massi_102011_FNC_MED.mp4" }
>   ["media-player"]=> array(1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["url"]=>
>   string(91)
>   "http://video.foxnews.com/assets/video-player.swf?video_id=1228085488001&d=video.foxnews.com"
>   } } ["media-description"]=> string(39) "Real estate expert Bob Massi
>   sounds off" ["media-thumbnail"]=> string(70)
>   "http://video.foxnews.com/thumbnails/102011/640/360/ff_massi_102011.jpg"
>   ["media-keywords"]=> array(0) { } ["media-credit"]=> string(16)
>   "foxnews1-foxnews" ["mvn-assetUUID"]=> string(13) "1228085488001"
>   ["mvn-mavenId"]=> array(0) { } ["mvn-creationDate"]=> string(25)
>   "2011-10-20T08:38:49-04:00" ["mvn-airDate"]=> string(25)
>   "2011-10-20T08:38:49-04:00" ["mvn-shortDescription"]=> string(20) "Bob
>   Massi sounds off" ["mvn-mitvAudioOnly"]=> string(5) "false"
>   ["mvn-fnc_mp3"]=> array(0) { } ["mvn-fnc_grab_50x50"]=> string(68)
>   "http://video.foxnews.com/thumbnails/102011/50/50/ff_massi_102011.jpg"
>   ["mvn-fnc_grab_103x58"]=> string(69)
>   "http://video.foxnews.com/thumbnails/102011/103/58/ff_massi_102011.jpg"
>   ["mvn-fnc_grab_156x88"]=> string(69)
>   "http://video.foxnews.com/thumbnails/102011/156/88/ff_massi_102011.jpg"
>   ["mvn-flv1200"]=> string(60)
>   "http://media2.foxnews.com/102011/ff_massi_102011_FNC_MED.mp4"
>   ["mvn-fnc_framework"]=> array(0) { } ["mvn-fnc_channel"]=> string(6)
>   "on_air" ["mvn-domain"]=> array(0) { } ["mvn-duration"]=> string(3)
>   "188" ["mvn-fnc_feedTag"]=> array(0) { } ["mvn-fnc_format"]=>
>   string(2) "NA" ["mvn-fnc_category"]=> string(35)
>   "on_air|fox_friends|shattered_dreams" ["mvn-fnc_category2"]=>
>   string(26) "personality|brian_kilmeade" ["mvn-fnc_show"]=> string(2)
>   "NA" ["mvn-fnc_default_playlist"]=> array(0) { }
>   ["mvn-fnc_personality"]=> string(2) "NA" ["mvn-fnc_mp4"]=> string(61)
>   "http://media2.foxnews.com/102011/ff_massi_102011_FNC_HIGH.mp4"
>   ["mvn-fnc_grab_320x240"]=> string(70)
>   "http://video.foxnews.com/thumbnails/102011/320/240/ff_massi_102011.jpg"
>   ["mvn-fnc_grab_90x70"]=> string(68)
>   "http://video.foxnews.com/thumbnails/102011/90/70/ff_massi_102011.jpg"
>   ["mvn-source"]=> string(8) "Fox News" } } } }

**When I do this:**

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://video.foxnews.com/v/feed/video/1228085488001.js"); 
var_dump(json_decode($contents->contents->channel->item->title, true));
```

**It outputs:**

```
NULL
```

**What can I do to just get these variables from the .js file:**

```
contents->channel->item->**title**
contents->channel->item->media-content->**media-description**
contents->channel->item->media-content->**mvn-fnc_grab_103x58**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By specifying `true` as the last parameter to `json_decode`, you're telling it to decode into an associative array. If you want to access the elements using object notation, don't use `true` as the last parameter:

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://video.foxnews.com/v/feed/video/1228085488001.js"); 
var_dump(json_decode($contents));
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this and it came out as NULL `var_dump(json_decode($contents->contents[0]->channel->item->title));`

Comment: That'll come out null because you're trying to access the properties of an object that doesn't exist yet ($contents is just a string). You have to call json_decode first, then use the properties accessor on that result object.

Comment: Ok, I tried this: `$cool = json_decode($contents); echo $cool->contents->channel->item->title;` and I ended up with nothing. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're making an easily-fixed mistake: there is no 'contents' element in the JSON at that source, so you really want `echo $cool->channel->item->title`. `var_dump`ing each step of the way is something that can be helpful.